# How do you say "Leo is sticking it to everyone" in French?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, registre-familier, vulgarité

How do you say "Leo is sticking it to everyone" in French?
[image]

Comment: As long as the photo accompanies the translation you’re after, you could consider going the subtle route,leaving any vulgarity to the reader’s imagination with “Leo [nous] montre ce qu'il pense" (Leo shows/showing [us] what he’s thinking).

Comment: @PapaPoule, bien trouvé ; ça donne mieux avec « Il nous montre ce qu'il en pense ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that a great translation exists for this expression, but might I suggest:

> Leo se fout de (la gueule de) tout le monde.

or the less vulgar:

> Leo se moque de tout le monde.

Comment: I like Leo se moque de tout le monde